# CodeIgniter config charset and UTF-8 support

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, character-encoding

I'm working on a website which uses / stores accented characters in the database. I have the page template set so that the **config.php** charset variable matches the setting, e.g.:

```
<meta charset="<?php echo $this->config->item('charset');?>">
```

The problem I'm having is, when `$config['charset']` is set to **UTF-8**, the form validation fails and it's as if no characters were submitted if an accented character was included. So, for example, a required field will bounce back if á is included anywhere in the string. The string minus the á works fine.

I've managed to get this working by changing the `$config['charset']` to **ISO-8859-1** and converting text to UTF-8 before inserting / after retrieving from the database with php's `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()`. Is this the best way or am I missing something needed in order to get UTF-8, with accented characters, working in CodeIgniter?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you set everywhere UTF-8. It is hard to tell what goes wrong, but probably at some point you have a different character set. Must read: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to make sure that you use UTF-8 everywhere, and that both PHP and MySQL are configure to handle UTF-8.

In the html, add the meta-tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

And save it in UTF-8 format. here is [how to do that in notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/21135/how-can-i-edit-unicode-text-in-notepad).

Define the MySQL tables to support UTF-8, create table with:

```
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And set the connection to:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
```

[Enable UTF-8](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) in the `php.ini`:

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

For a full manual check [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer and link - I'll check to make sure UTF-8 is being used throughout. The form validation problem was being caused by the $config['charset'] setting being set to 'UTF-8' (all uppercase) rather than 'utf-8' (all lowercase). For some reason the default setting for this being uppercase 'UTF-8' doesn't work (at least not on my setup).

Comment: Small comment for people who found it on google - alternative source of this problem might be encoding of the table _or column_ (yes, changing encoding of the table does not change the encoding of individual columns) - in that case editing value within a column with UTF-8 string would result in "Incorrect string value” warning, which is not visible when you simply run query through codeigniter. All you'll see is ? instead of UTF-8 char.