# My CI doesn't run queries properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I've set my unicode settings correct in codeigniter.

I want to run the query :

> SELECT * FROM (`restaurants`) WHERE `restaurant_name` LIKE 'دالون'

but codeigniter runs :

> SELECT * FROM (`restaurants`) WHERE `restaurant_name` LIKE
>   '%\%D8\%AF\%D8\%A7\%D9\%84\%D9\%88\%D9\%86%'

and no results are returned?

I need help...

Comment: change the correct set and collations your db and tables to `utf8` and `ci_general_utf8`

Comment: This might be helpful: [CodeIgniter config charset and UTF-8 support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158043/codeigniter-config-charset-and-utf-8-support)

Answer (score 1):

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

for example in mysqli functions

```
$MySQL_Handle = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME,DATABASE_USERNAME,DATABASE_PASSWORD,DATABASE_NAME) 
or die ( mysqli_error($MySQL_Handle) ); 

$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'; 

mysqli_query($MySQL_Handle,$sSQL) 
or die ('Can\'t charset in DataBase');
```

this action need before insert and before select.