# Updating php breaks UTF-8 encoding in German language Codeigniter 1 site

Tags: php, codeigniter, encoding, utf-8

I have inherited an elderly Codeigniter 1.0 site with German language content.   Arg.

It was running on a server with php 5.2 and MySQL 5.0.

Updating the server to use php 5.4 and MySQL 5.5 caused the character encoding to fall to bits - I assume Codeigniter is running the database content (which is correct) through some sort of filter.

It now shows, for example, **Ã¼**  where the database has **ü**

Everything is set to UTF-8, and nothing on the site itself has changed, although the database has been updated of course.

Any ideas where I could look to find out where this is happening and give it a stern talking to?  Please use small words if you have a suggestion, because I don't know codeigniter very well. :-D

**EDIT1**

I have the charset in the HTML set to utf-8 - that hasn't changed.
All the tables have collation : utf8_unicode_ci 
in config/database.php, I have:
 $db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

**EDIT2**
As suggested by Chococroc, I created a test php file to pull the data direct from the database.  This displayed the German characters correctly, but helped me to realise that in the database, HTML is being stored as HTML entities - `&lt;p&gt;` instead of `<p>` for example.

Could it be that whatever is turning these entities back into HTML is also mangling the German characters...?

Comment: Just to discard it's not from the view, has the page you want to show <meta charset="utf-8"> in the header?

Comment: More things, did you check this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158043/codeigniter-config-charset-and-utf-8-support, Just to be totally sure is a Codeigniter issue

Comment: Yes, I think I've checked all those, but thanks very much for trying - I'll update my question with these extra details.

Comment: ummm... I answered with some CI configurations, check if anything of it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you checked all in [CodeIgniter config charset and UTF-8 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158043/codeigniter-config-charset-and-utf-8-support), well, let's dive into CI, according to this post: http://www.jamipietila.fi/codeigniter-and-utf-8/ there are three places to look into:

Config.php

```
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8";
```

Database.php

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Controllers:
Add this line

```
$this->output->set_header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Last try if nothing works: If after ALL of this, it's still not working, check with a simple PHP file with a PDO to go to the DDBB and retrieve and output the results. If with that the utf-8 works, it's sure is something INSIDE CI. If not, it's your server, something that it doesn't like when you changed to PHP 5.4

Comment: I've already got those lines in config.php and database.php, but I'm not clear where to put the extra line in Controllers -  I put it in /controllers/home.php and /controllers/page.php as an extra line in function show_page() and function index() - was that right?  If so, alas, it did not help.

Comment: I tried pulling the fields direct from the database in php, and the german characters displayed correctly.  So that means it must be inside CI ...?

Comment: OK, pulling the database records into a file outside CI was really helpful - I realised that the HTML in the database was stored as entities, and that therefore, something must be turning those entities back into HTML.  This led me to html_entity_decode, and looking for instances of that,led me to the fact that utf8_encode was being used as well as  html_entity_decode. Removing utf8_encode function fixed the German characters.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter have utf-8 character input data save issue in some hosting servers like Etisalat. system/core/Utf8.php have function to detect illegal char in input data(post/get). In some cases utf-8 char is consider as illegal and save function will fail. For avoid data saving issue do the following in clean_string() function of Utf8.php at line 85.

$str = !mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', TRUE) ? utf8_encode($str) : $str;

$str = @iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str);