# Codeigniter: How to pass UTF8 parameters to a controller using url?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, utf-8, codeigniter-3

I'm using Code-igniter 3 and need to pass a parameter to a controller using URL parameters. My URL is something like this:

```
http://192.168.40.50/user/list/محمد
```

And I added this to the config file :

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-|آ-ی';
```

And my controller is like this:

```
public function list($name)
{ 
    // The $name parameter is incorrect here
    // In this case $name = 'E-E'
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting 'E-E' instead of 'محمد'.

I just search a lot of questions but didn't find a solution

**َUPDATE**

I'm using routing. The parameters are delivered correctly without routing but when I add routes UTF-8 characters are changed. My route is just like this:

```
$route['user/list/(:any)'] = 'user/list_of/$1';
```

Comment: for this did you try echo ``urldecode($name)`` inside list function ?

Comment: urldecode is not working

Answer (score 0):

Phil Sturgeon explains allowing UTF-8 extensively: here is an excerpt followed by the full article link:

Set the HTTP header in index.php
All requests to CodeIgniter are made through the index.php file which by default sits outside the system/ folder. For this reason it makes a perfect place to add a PHP header for me.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Tell CodeIgniter what's going on
CodeIgniter by default is set to use UTF-8 for much of its internal functionality, so just make sure the charset is set to UTF-8 in your application/config/config.php file.

```
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8";
```

Configure database connection

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8"; $db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_unicode_ci";
```

At this point you should be able to use the UTF-8 Characters, if you want to save it into the DB which I am using you would do, read on further using this link:

[USING UTF-8](https://philsturgeon.uk/codeigniter/2009/08/17/UTF-8-support-for-CodeIgniter/)

You can also refer to this stackoverflow post:
[Using UTF-8 Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158043/codeigniter-config-charset-and-utf-8-support)

Comment: Thanks. I did them all. But the $name variable still has the wrong value. For example '(\'̯\'F�' instead of 'بایگانی'

Comment: read the rest of Phil Sturgeon's post, there is some extra information concerning adding a META to the HTML, aside adding content header type to the index.php. 

There is also some other resources he's proposed you look at.

Comment: that's not case of headers anymore i think, he just need to urldecode the param

Comment: I found out that the problem only occurs when using routes. I updated the question