# How to print Chinese, Japanese and Korean strings in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, cjk

I'm working on a PHP site that needs both Chinese, Japanese and Korean. , but I can't get the characters to display if I print a string like this:

views/index.php

```
echo "改コ視崎ノ連代極カ例読作壊てっイぶ覚代間みょトー偏進どわへ改化ロ終面ヌ政事ろづゆぞ期欲ノラ";
```

I get "????????????????". Is there any way for me to get my echo to print the data to the browser a way it can read it?

I tried with following code but these won't work for me

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

in codeignator index file i added following header

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: there is a config option in your `config.php`. Try to set `$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';` maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158043/codeigniter-config-charset-and-utf-8-support and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-apache helps ...

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps

1) In your `application/config/config.php` file, update this

```
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
```

2) If you are displaying data from database, change your database table column collation to `utf8_general_ci`.

Answer (score 0):

Change charset in config file as below-

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

to

```
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
```

If this is not working, use the javascript encodeURI function to encodeURI the data, before u post.